# AWS instance gateway using Amazon Linux

Tags: networking, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm trying to create a gateway on an aws ec2 amazon linux machine so that a worker machine without access to the internet can gain access via the gateway. Then I will install a server on it and apache2 load balancer on the gateway machine to redirect http requests to worker machines. The way I would usually do it on debian and a local virtual environment would be:

on gateway machine:

- enable ipv4 forwarding
- add iptable rule for postrouting masquerading
- restart network

on worker machine:

- add default gateway to /etc/network/interfaces
- restart network

And that's it. On the amazon linux machine, being a redhat based distro, I do it the following way:

- enable ipv4 forwarding
- `add iptable rule for postrouting masquerading`
- restart network

on worker machine:

- `ip route add default via GATEWAY_MACHINE_IP`

And then it's just hangs because I lost my ssh connection. I also tried modifying the interface file in /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ and I lose the ssh connection when restarting the network.

The gateway machine is in a security group that allows all ipv4 incoming connections from all sources and ssh from my local computer, and allows all outgoing traffic to any destination.

The worker machine is in a different security group that allows all traffic from and to the gateway machine and ssh from my local computer.

Something I've noticed is that AWS only uses one interface for public and private connections, so maybe that has something to do with what's going on?

I was hoping somebody give me some insight as to what I'm doing wrong and if it's even possible to do what I'm trying to do in AWS

Answer (score 0):

A forward proxy (kindof an internet gateway) and a reverse proxy (load balancer) on the same machine? That generally won't work in AWS.

In AWS a forward proxy (private subnet to internet) requires the source / destination check to be disabled. The reverse proxy requires it to be enabled.

You should use two different servers. Alternately you can use AWS managed services, a NAT Gateway which is a managed forward proxy, and an application load balancer which is a reverse proxy.